# i may be using the div tag in wrong way please tell me the appropriate way

Tags: html, css

```css
.one {
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <div class="one">
   <td>td 1</td>
   <td>td 2</td>
  </div>
  <td>td 3</td>
</tr>
```

this css command is not working, i want to turn two of the "td" cells into green but it is not happening tell me where i am going wrong. when I write "td" or "tr" instead of one(class name) then it is working properly but not with this class.

Comment: create the div inside the td.you cannot add div tags directly in the tr.

Answer (score 1):

You should add class "one" to td directly, for your question `div` is not necessary element.

```
<tr>
    <td class="one">td 1</td>
    <td class="one">td 2</td>
    <td>td 3</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: thanks it's running now, but why i can't add div outside the td ?

Comment: `td` stands for table cell. `div` is another way to organise HTML page. You could insert whole <table> into `div`, or `div` into table cell (like `td`), but you can't mix a half of table with divs